# Execute git fetch in Ant Tasks with password to repo

Tags: git, ant, hudson

I am trying to use some git commands in Ant Tasks.

```
<macrodef name = "git">
  <attribute name = "command" />
  <attribute name = "dir" default = "" />
  <attribute name="failonerror" default="false"/>
  <element name = "args" optional = "true" />
  <sequential>
    <echo message = "git @{command}" />
    <exec executable = "C:\Git\cmd\git.exe" dir = "@{dir}">
      <arg value = "@{command}" />
      <args/>
    </exec>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>

<git command = "fetch" dir = "git_src" failonerror = "true"/>
```

But when I start my job in Hudson it stucks on it, it's not ending on failure, just do nothing. Probably it needs password to repo (git bash is asking for it, when I use this command by myself).

Is there any option to do it automaticly? I should use some specific tools to do it or can I do it by exec in Ant?

Comment: can you use password-less ssh access to avoid explicit password?

Comment: Thanks! There were some troubles linking Linux server and Windows client with ssh access, but it actually works.